# Where does the definition for energy in PDE come from in physics

Tags: optics, energy, waves, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

We defined energy in the context of the wave equation in my PDE class to be 
$$
E(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(u_t^2+[\nabla_{\vec{x}} u]^2\right)d^n\vec{x}
$$
Where $u$ satisfies the wave equation
$$
u_{tt}-\Delta u=0
$$
It's a conserved quantity in the system, but I am wondering whether there is a better physical explanation for this definition of energy.

It is pretty clear that the $u_t^2$ term represents a kinetic energy, but I don't have good intuition for why the other term should be potential energy. I know this is system dependent, but why does it make sense here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given an arbitrary [PDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation), an energy functional might not exist. But if it exists, the construction usually fits into the following template:

1. Find a Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ for the PDE. This means that the Euler-Lagrange equation for ${\cal L}$ should reproduce the PDE. In OP's case the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ is of the form ${\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{u}^2-{\cal V}(u,\nabla u),$ where ${\cal V}(u,\nabla u)$ is the potential energy density. Here $\dot{u}$ and $\nabla u$ denote the temporal and spatial derivatives, respectively.
2. The Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ typically doesn't depend explicitly on $t$. [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) then guarantees that there exists a conserved quantity. The zero-component  $$j^0~=~\left(\dot{u}\frac{\partial }{\partial\dot{u}}-1\right){\cal L}$$ of the Noether current is the energy density. The corresponding Noether charge $Q=\int  \!d^nx~j^0 $ is the sought-for energy functional.